# Android mapview zoom control 'lingering'

Tags: android, dictionary, tabs

I have an Android tab layout with three tabs, one of which has a mapview activity. Within this, I am using

```
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

However, once I've activated the map, and then click on one of the other tabs in my tabwidget, the zoom controls remain in view. How can I get them to vanish when I'm not in the map tab?

I can't post an image, as I'm too new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted - I had left in a rogue:

```
mapView.getZoomButtonsController().setAutoDismissed(false);
```

command that was several lines of code below the bit I was working on. My stupidity.